# InvocationTargetException:There was an error while invoking the operation. Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash-builder

I am having issues getting my remote server configured right after everything working properly on the local host. I am getting the following error:

```
InvocationTargetException:There was an error while invoking the operation. Check your operation inputs or server code and try invoking the operation again.
```

The key parts of the large message I am getting after that are:

```
Class "test" does not exist: Plugin by name 'Test' was not found in the registry; used paths:: 
..../smii/test/ID5D8FE3F-A1D1-4174-98B3-4BED10FD8FFEI79685B66-D792-E4E9-13B3-00004DA5951BI0F94D267-0704-3C89-0B5B-0000090BA097134950398900
```

I don't know how this last part of the address with random number and letters is getting there.

Also, when searching for my server settings today it seems to add a "-1" on the end of the initial directory on the server not sure why but I seem to be having major issues implementing the service remotely.

Comment: why you have added php tag ? I don't get any relation with PHP